# Control the name for a constraint in django

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, mariadb

I have the problem that I need to replace a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint, generated by django, by a `ON DELETE CASCADE` constraint. What I want to do is to extend the django generated migration to implement the following with `RunSQL`:

1. Drop the constraint generated by Django with `DROP FOREIGN KEY`
2. Create a new constraint with `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

To perform the first operation, I need the name of the FOREIGN KEY constraint, but this is automatically generated by django.

How can I force the name of a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint? (*not* the name of the FOREIGN KEY column, which is a different thing)

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution: do not allow django to create the foreign key constraint in the first place. This can be achived with `db_constraint=False`:

```
tenant = models.ForeignKey(Tenant, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, db_constraint=False)
```

After that, you can put any constraint you like, using `migrations.RunSQL`.